# Is there any way to add association at the time of create model using sails blueprints api?

Tags: sails.js

I would like to a add an association when a creating a row using sails blueprints api  /model/craete.

Below is my message.js Model

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
      text : {
        type: 'string'
      },
      from : {
        model: 'user'
      },
      chat : {
        model: 'chat'
      }
  }
};
```

How can I add "from" and "chat" when creating message using blueprint api.

Comment: Can you be more clear what you want to do? Is it one-one or what type of association ?

Comment: Hi M U, I updated the question with model details. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Just put `'user.id` in 'user' field and `chat.id` in `chat` field of mode.

Comment: When I tried this it didn't work now I realised it's a typo mistake from my side I did /message/craete.

Comment: Can you let me know how can we do the same for collection ? 
I want to add users involved in chat when creating chat. Chat is model with users as a collection.

Comment: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/add-to  Would be nice to vote up and choose answer as accepted as little thank you for help...